# Javascript active class only gets applied to first list item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on some code for a portfolio where the projects are shown on the left-hand side.

The active class is supposed to be added to the classes of the line left div for any list item, however, when I mouse over any other of the project-title list items it only works for the first one, I am not sure why this is? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="project">
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">Project title</p>
  </li>
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">Project title</p>
  </li>
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">Project title</p>
  </li>
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">Project title</p>
  </li>
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">Project title</p>
  </li>
  <li class=project-title>
    <div class="line-left"></div>
    <p class="project-paragraph">
      Project title</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.project {
  width: 170px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #949394;
}

.project-title {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.project-paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
}

.line-left {
  border-top: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.querySelector('.project-title').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  document.querySelector('.project-title .line-left').classList.add('active');
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/andylyell/ynb7wxk2/

I would love to have only 1 active class present on a line left, anytime but I am unsure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thank you!

Comment: The `.querySelector()` function only returns the first matching element it finds. You probably want `.querySelectorAll()`, though it'd be simpler still if you just did it with event delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe each element that have "project-title" class.
Here is modified js for you solution:

```
var activeClassName = 'active';
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.project-title');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    subscribeEvent(elements[i]);
}
function subscribeEvent(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    if (containsClass(target.querySelector('.line-left'), activeClassName))     {
        return;
    }
    setActiveEl(target);
  }, false);
}
function setActiveEl(activeEl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      if (element != activeEl) {
        removeClass(element.querySelector('.line-left'), activeClassName);
      }
    }
    addClass(activeEl.querySelector('.line-left'), activeClassName);
}
function addClass(el, className) {
    el && el.classList.add(className);
}
function removeClass(el, className) {
    el && el.classList.remove(className);
}
function containsClass(el, className) {
    return el && el.classList.contains(className);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use--

```
document.querySelectorAll('.project-title').addEventListener('mouseover', 
 function() {
 document.querySelectorAll('.project-title .line-  
   left').classList.add('active');
  });
```

Then you will be able to add that class to all the elements having that class